# Month to date query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

How do I make a query run for current month and current day of that month?

For example :

```
Select 
    installed_date,
    cust_no,
    sum(Price) as daily_price
From 
    table1
Group By 
    installed_date, 
    cust_no
```

I want this query to always return current month's data so in this case from `1st Dec 2013` till `3rd Dec 2013`.

Thanks

Comment: What is your DB, is mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select installed_date,cust_no,sum(Price) as daily_price
from table1
where installed_date >= dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, current_timestamp), 0)
group by installed_date,cust_no
```

Comment: wow i love these men that can answer without knowing what's the SGBD behind, respect ;)

Comment: @user2196728 It's a guess, for Sql Server, but even if it's not sql server, that code uses the functions defined by the ansi sql standard.

Comment: sure, but before guessing, i just ask the question....usually a best practice... ;) but nevermind, hope this will help this guy ! cheers

Comment: I didn't think that SQL Server's `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` were part of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

[Click on this link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/284282/26)

Check above link.
I have created a table with three column. Schema of same is added to this link.
Also wrote a query which will resolve your problem. Have a look. I am not mysql developer but tried to convert mssql query to mysql. If you want MSSQL query then revert.